# C# Read stdout of child process asynchronously

Tags: c#

I am working with C# and having trouble understanding how to read *stdout* asynchronously from a child process. What I want to do is create a child process that executes an application and then present whatever is received from that process' stdout in a textbox. I need to see every output character from the child process immediately and can not wait for a line to complete, therefore I don't think that the `Process.OutputDataReceived` event suits my purpose. Can you tell me a sane way to accomplish this?

I have tried calling `Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead()` and passing a call-back function to it, but in this call-back function I receive an exception from `Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.EndRead()`.

My code looks like this (the child process is a script engine - abbreviated "SE" - for verifying the functionality of an external device. Scripts are executed in sequence and each script requires one instance of the SE application)

```
private bool startScript()
{
  // Starts the currently indexed script

  if (null != scriptList)
  {

    if (0 == scriptList.Count || scriptListIndexer == scriptList.Count)
    {
      // If indexer equals list count then there are no active scripts in
      // the list or the last active script in the list has just finished
      return false;                              // ## RETURN ##
    }
    if (ScriptExecutionState.RUNNING == scriptList[scriptListIndexer].executionState)
    {
      return false;                              // ## RETURN ##
    }

    if (0 == SE_Path.Length)
    {
      return false;                              // ## RETURN ##
    }

    SE_Process = new Process();
    SE_Process.StartInfo.FileName = SE_Path;
    SE_Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    SE_Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    SE_Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    SE_Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    SE_Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    SE_Process.StartInfo.Arguments = scriptList[scriptListIndexer].getParameterString();

    // Subscribe to process exit event
    SE_Process.Exited += new EventHandler(SE_Process_Exited);

    try
    {
      if (SE_Process.Start())
      {
        // Do stuff
      }
      else
      {
        // Do stuff
      }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
      // Do stuff
    }

    // Assign 'read_SE_StdOut()' as call-back for the event of stdout-data from SE
    SE_Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(SE_StdOutBuffer, 0, SE_BUFFERSIZE, read_SE_StdOut, null);

    return true;                                       // ## RETURN ##

  }
  else
  {
    return false;                                      // ## RETURN ##
  }
}

private void read_SE_StdOut(IAsyncResult result)
{
  try
  {
    int bytesRead = SE_Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.EndRead(result);  // <-- Throws exceptions

    if (0 != bytesRead)
    {
      // Write the received data in output textbox
      ...
    }

    // Reset the callback
    SE_Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(SE_StdOutBuffer, 0, SE_BUFFERSIZE,     read_SE_StdOut, null);
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    // Do stuff
  }
}

void SE_Process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  // Keep track of whether or not the next script shall be started
  bool continueSession = false;

  switch (SE_Process.ExitCode)
  {
    case 0: // PASS
    {
      // Do stuff
    }

    ...

  }

  SE_Process.Dispose(); // TODO: Is it necessary to dispose of the process?

  if (continueSession)
  {
    ts_incrementScriptListIndexer();

    if (scriptListIndexer == scriptList.Count)
    {
      // Last script has finished, reset the indexer and re-enable
      // 'scriptListView'
      ...
    }
    else
    {
      if (!startScript())
      {
        // Do stuff
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    ts_resetScriptListIndexer();
    threadSafeEnableScriptListView();
  }
}
```

What happens is that after one SE process finishes I get an exception of type `InvalidOperationException` that says

> StandardOut has not been redirected or
>   the process hasn't started yet.

from the call to `SE_Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.EndRead()`. I do not understand why because I have set `SE_Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` before start of every new process. It appears to me as if the stdout stream of an exited process calls my `read_SE_StdOut()` function after the process has been disposed, is that possible?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: You may be interested in the [MedallionShell](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionShell) library, which simplifies dealing with process io streams, particularly async operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you get is normal.  One `BeginRead()` call can never succeed: the last one, just after the process terminates.  You'd normally avoid calling `BeginRead()` again if you know the process is completed so you don't get the exception.  However, you'd rarely know.  Just catch the exception.  Or use `BeginOutputReadLine()` instead, it will catch it for you.

I'm guessing that you also redirect *stderr* and that the tool uses it to output "X".  There is no way to keep output on both *stderr* and *stdout* synchronized after it is buffered and redirected.

Comment: I see, I'll just handle the exception then.
Regarding the disturbed order of the characters; also the X:es are put out on stdout so I don't think that explains why they are presented out of order. I'll let this question remain unanswered because my biggest problem is the incorrect display of the output (I thought it might have been related to the exception somehow but maybe it isn't). Thank you for your answer!

Comment: My problem with the disordered display of received characters no longer occurs, I must have fixed it by accident :)
I've removed that part of the question above and set the question to "answered".
Thanks again!