# Unable to read output from child process from C# app using async methods?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process, stdout, stdin

I am trying to write my own interactive shell for an EXE on my Windows 8.1 box, using C# and Visual Studio 2013, Update 4.  The code runs without any errors, but I never see anything back from the Read call in either the loop that reads from stdout or the loop that reads stderr.  The read calls never return.  What is wrong with my approach?

I saw this related SO post but I am not getting any Exceptions thrown at all:

[C# Read stdout of child process asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085778/c-sharp-read-stdout-of-child-process-asynchronously)

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private const string DIR_CHILDPROCESS = @"C:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\ChildProcess-5.3.1 - IDAvatars\";
    private const string EXE_NAME = @"childprocess.exe";

    Process _childProcess = null;

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task ReadOutputFromChildProcess()
    {
        char[] aryC = new char[1];

        while (true)
        {
            // Get output from ChildProcess.
            int count = await this._childProcess.StandardOutput.ReadAsync(aryC, 0, 1);

            Debug.Write(aryC[0]);

            // await Task.Delay(50);
        }
    }

    private async Task ReadFromErrorsChildProcess()
    {
        char[] aryC = new char[1];

        while (true)
        {
            // Get output from ChildProcess.
            int count = await this._childProcess.StandardError.ReadAsync(aryC, 0, 1);

            Debug.Write(aryC[0]);

            // await Task.Delay(50);
        }
    }

    private void frmShell_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string target = Path.Combine(DIR_CHILDPROCESS, EXE_NAME);

        this._childProcess = new Process();

        this._childProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        this._childProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        this._childProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        this._childProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        this._childProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 

        this._childProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        this._childProcess.StartInfo.FileName = target;

        this._childProcess.Exited += this._childProcess_Exited;

        // this._childProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        // this._childProcess.StartInfo.
        this._childProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = DIR_CHILDPROCESS;
        //this._childProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(DIR_CHILDPROCESS, EXE_NAME);
        //this._childProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //this._childProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //this._childProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        //this._childProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        //this._childProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;


        if (!this._childProcess.Start())
            MessageBox.Show("ChildProcess failed to start.", "Error");

        // Start the loop that reads output from ChildProcess.
        this.ReadOutputFromChildProcess();

        // Start the loop that reads error messages from ChildProcess.
        this.ReadFromErrorsChildProcess();

        Debug.WriteLine("ChildProcess launched successfully.");

        // this._childProcess.WaitForExit();

    }

    void _childProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Child process exited with exit code: " + this._childProcess.ExitCode.ToString());
    }

    private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this._childProcess.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the child process exit? If not, you might want to close its input handle. Is it actually producing output, and if it is, is it actually writing to its output stream or is it sending it directly to its console? I.e., try executing the app in cmd with redirected output; does that work?

Comment: @StephenCleary - I want to keep the child process alive as long as the host shell app is alive so it doesn't exit (I double-checked this by making sure the child process was showing in the Task Manager).  It definitely is producing output.  I tried redirecting output from a CMD launch and nothing appeared in the capture file.  So I assume this means it is writing directly to the console instead of StdOut?  If so how do I capture output in that case?  I assume it must be possible because CMD and other shells do so.

Comment: Technically, it's not possible to keep the child app "alive"; it'll quit whenever it wants to; the best you can do is keep a reference to it (as a zombie process). Sounds like your child app is writing directly to the console, [which is bad for you](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/capture-console-win32.html). Best solutions available (both bad): either [p/Invoke some nasty APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684206(v=vs.85).aspx) or [hook the child process' calls](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks.  No problem with keeping the child app alive.  It doesn't exit until you type in "quit". On the second point the child app is a C++ app that uses printf().  Not confirmed yet, but it looks like printf() does print to stdout on Linux, but not Win32.  Perhaps a C++ CRT lib thing?  Found this post on it:  http://www.gamedev.net/topic/567624-printf-statement-not-generating-stdout-file-in-visual-c/

Comment: @StephenCleary - Looks like apps built with Visual Studio that use printf don't output to Stdout: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/printf-stdout-do-not-work-on-win32/315/2

Comment: I'm unsure about whether `printf` uses streams or low-level console I/O, but if it does use streams you may need to explicitly flush them.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks will do.

Answer (score 2):

> I saw this related SO post but I am not getting any Exceptions thrown
>   at all

Any exception propogated from any of the async methods will be swallowed inside both `Task` objects, which you aren't awaiting any of. If you want to observe any exception, you can execute both async operations concurrently and await them both using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
private async void frmShell_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var readOutputTask = this.ReadOutputFromChildProcess();
    var readErrorTask = this.ReadFromErrorsChildProcess();

    await Task.WhenAll(readOutputTask, readErrorTask);
}
```

Otherwise, if you want both operations to execute sequentially, you can `await` each one separately:

```
private async void frmShell_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ReadOutputFromChildProcess();
    await ReadFromErrorsChildProcess();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did as you suggested and used "await Task.WhenAll()".  However I am still not getting any Exceptions or any results from my Read() calls.  Oddly enough, the read calls do finally return something when I close the main form, on the way to exiting the app.  The form Load event is at the top of the stack at this point.  I'm beginning to wonder if some kind of blocking is taking place.

Comment: Interesting.  The reason I get something to happen when closing the app is because my code has (had) errors in it for the Debug.Write() statements.  I was using ary[1] instead of ary[0], causing an index out of range Exception.  Once I corrected that mistake, the breakpoints on the Debug.Write() statements were no longer hit when closing the app.  Note, I just corrected those statements in the code in my post.

Comment: @Robert So is the current status?

Comment: Still not running.  Despite changing my code as you suggested, I am not getting any Exceptions and I am not getting any results back from the Read calls.

Comment: @RobertOschler Is the process actually outputing anything to the output stream? Can you see anything perhaps with process monitor?