# Not able to interact with wpf element while a method executing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a WPF application with 2 buttons. On the click of first button executing a cmd and waiting for finishing of command because I need to read a result file after execution finish. On the second button click I am stopping execution of cmd by process kill.

But after start command execution, I am not able to stop execution before finishing execution of cmd.

Is there any way of parallel execution?

Start button code

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "nunit-console.exe");
 Process proc = Process.Start(filename, "/result:" + resultFile + ".xml " + fileName);
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Use [Multithreading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm), as your main thread gets freezed while waiting for `proc.WaitForExit();`

Comment: @Nobody is correct. To ellaborate a bit, your UI has its own thread and there needs to be some rules followed to have your UI update from or change other threads. Look into async/await and updating to/from UI Thread. plenty of examples and tutorials out there.

Comment: Note that you may or may not actually need to use `WaitForExit()`. It depends on the rest of the code, which you didn't bother to show. The `Process` class offers asynchronous handling of I/O and state handling. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085778/c-sharp-read-stdout-of-child-process-asynchronously. Running the above code in a background task or thread is the most obvious approach to a literal reading of your question, but there are other ways to address it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `proc.WaitForExit();`. This line is blocking the interface thread, preventing the second button click to be registered.

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc;

    private void Btn1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "nunit-console.exe");
        proc = Process.Start(filename, "/result:" + resultFile + ".xml " + fileName);
    }

    private void Btn2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (proc != null)
            proc.Kill();
    }
```